# Making an async COM call -- do I have to create my own P/S?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, ole-automation

I have a custom interface defined in a type library and implemented in my code. I have not created my own proxy/stub. I have successfully marshaled the interface pointer from my main thread (STA) to a background thread (STA), in my case using [IGlobalInterfaceTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678517.aspx).

From that background thread, I want to make an asynchronous call to the object on the UI thread. I have not implemented [ICallFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680133.aspx) in my object. I see that the standard proxy does indeed implement [ICallFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680133.aspx) (i.e, I can successfully QI on the background thread for [ICallFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680133.aspx)). But the [CreateCall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688577.aspx) for my custom interface fails with HRESULT 0x80040150 (Could not read key from registry).

Do I need to create my own proxy that explicitly implements [ICallFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680133.aspx) in order to do this?

Here's my IDL:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(92303FE7-A79D-47DD-923F-62062105C00E),
    async_uuid(2880C40C-9965-4544-AE39-DF08056E8CB6),
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique),
    oleautomation
]
interface IFoo: IUnknown
{
    HRESULT Foo([in] long a, [in] long b);
}

[
    uuid(D58B0A31-A2D5-4BFB-8702-3B710320493B)
]
coclass Foo
{
    [default] interface IFoo;
};
```

And here's the background thread proc in my unit test:

```
    static DWORD WINAPI threadproc(LPVOID lpParameter)
    {
        // get arguments
        DWORD cookie = *(DWORD*)lpParameter;

        // initialize COM
        Assert::AreEqual(S_OK, CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));
        {
            // get global interface table
            IGlobalInterfaceTablePtr globalInterfaceTable;
            Assert::AreEqual(S_OK, globalInterfaceTable.CreateInstance(CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable));

            // get object
            MyLib::IFooPtr object;
            Assert::AreEqual(S_OK, globalInterfaceTable->GetInterfaceFromGlobal(cookie, MyLib::IID_IFoo, (LPVOID*)&object));

            // get async call factory
            ICallFactoryPtr callFactory;
            Assert::AreEqual(S_OK, object->QueryInterface(&callFactory));

            //
            // Everything is fine up until the CreateCall call below,
            // which fails with HRESULT 0x80040150
            //

            // create async call object
            IUnknownPtr callObject;
            Assert::AreEqual(S_OK, callFactory->CreateCall(MyLib::IID_AsyncIFoo, NULL, IID_IUnknown, &callObject));
        }
        // uninitialize COM
        CoUninitialize();

        // success
        return 0;
    }
```

---

Comment: Show how you call `CreateCall`. What error does it fail with? Also, is your interface a dual interface (deriving from `IDispatch`), by any chance? From [this piece of documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692623.aspx): "**Note** Asynchronous support is not available for `IDispatch` or for interfaces that inherit `IDispatch`."

Comment: I did see that documentation and acted accordingly. However, I think I'm breaking the rules. As per the aforementioned documentation, the async stuff doesn't work with IDispatch. So my interface inherits only from IUnknown. However, the global interface table's GetInterfaceFromGlobal method fails with E_FAIL when the interface isn't marked [dual], which as I understand it must inherit from IDispatch. At this point, I've left [dual] in to make the marshaling work but took IDispatch out in hopes of making async calls work.

Comment: also: added error details

Comment: Seems [oleautomation] likewise solves the marshaling issue (and my interface is OLE Automation compatible, given the definitions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367129.aspx)). And interfaces marked [oleautomation] don't have to inherit from IDispatch. Testing ICallFactory now...

Comment: No luck. Will share my IDL.

Comment: Try mentioning `AsyncIFoo` in `coclass` clause in the IDL. I bet it's not described by the type library. `0x80040150` is `REGDB_E_READREGDB` "Could not read key from registry" - my guess is, it's the universal marshaler trying to read `HKCR\Interface\{AsyncIFoo IID}` to figure out how to marshal it. If that doesn't work, then I suspect you'll have to build proxy/stub DLL after all - TLB-driven marshaling won't cut it.

Comment: You don't need to create *custom* proxies, but you do need to create *default* proxies (and register them).

Comment: @Igor: That won't work. My coclass doesn't actually implement AsyncIFoo. Nor should it. The server that implements IXxx rarely (if ever) should implement AsyncIXxx. But I tried it and I get a MIDL compile warning: `error MIDL2337: unsatisfied forward declaration : AsyncIFoo [ Coclass 'Foo'  ]`

Comment: @Igor: AsyncIFoo is fully registered when I run RegisterTypeLib, so it's not a problem with the basic registration. Now, if there is additional registration required specifically for async that RegisterTypeLib doesn't do, that's another story, but I haven't seen anything about this, either online or in my own registry.

Comment: @Eric: Can you elaborate? When I call RegisterTypeLib, it automatically sets the ProxyStubClsid key for my interfaces to {00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} (PSOAInterface -- the default p/s for oleautomation interfaces). This p/s is being used during the marshal/unmarshal process already, so I know that's working.

Comment: @Igor: Ignore error from previous post. I had accidentally removed the async_uuid attribute from my IDL. With that attribute correctly applied, I can list AsyncIFoo in the interfaces for my coclass (although that still seems incorrect to me). This doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried actually implementing AsyncIFoo and ICallFactory in my coclass, however, no QI ever occurs for these interfaces on my object when using a proxy.

Comment: I've used Async COM with the RunningObjectTable (instead of the GlobalInterfaceTable), and to make that work, I had to build the proxy DLL that MIDL creates.   Looking at other usages of Async COM in the company, they're all using proxy DLLs as well.

Comment: Oh, and you need to *register* the proxy DLL as well.   There's a bunch of stuff that needs to be registered, and (based on my rather hazy memory) there are some extra keys that the proxy DLL knows about but the typelib registration does not.

Comment: Ah, that's the gist of my question -- do I need the custom (MIDL-provided) P/S. Sounds like you're saying yes.

Comment: Seconding @EricBrown. I had async COM calls working, a long time ago, using a proxy/stub DLL built from MIDL-generated sources. I haven't tried with universal marshaling, nor have I heard of anyone else trying that (until now). I can't say for sure it's impossible (it's difficult to prove a negative), but it sure seems this way. You've already tried everything I could think of, and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant a *custom* (non-MIDL provided) P/S..

Comment: This is probably bad form, but since you guys were able to help on this issue, maybe you could shed some light on this one -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266061/register-a-proxy-stub-in-hkey-current-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the universal marshaller does not work with Async COM.  You need to build the (MIDL-generated) proxy (although, IIRC, you can merge the stubs if you're building a DLL).

You also need to register the proxy DLL (and build it with the -DREGISTER_PROXY_DLL define).  Async COM needs more registry keys defined in order to make it work.