# Register a proxy/stub in HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Tags: winapi, com, registry, win32ole, ole-automation

The MIDL compiler generates code for a proxy/stub with registration routines that write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Is there any way (preferably without hacking the MIDL-generated code and without bypassing all that generated code in favor of custom code) to register a MIDL-generated p/s in HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

Also: Will this work if both the p/s and the COM server are registered per-user like this? I just found (after a very frustrating 48 hours) that a p/s registered machine-wide will not work correctly if the COM server is registered per-user. Specifically, the asynchronous call logic (ICallFactory::CreateCall) of the p/s will fail under these circumstances.

Comment: No, not really.  Proxy generation is highly automated "push the button, never a mistake that way" building.  The code lives in the `<RpcProxy.h>` SDK header file, it uses NdrDllRegisterProxy().  Nothing is impossible but you got to like making mistakes.

Comment: That's what I thought. I just manually set up my HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry and it does work. So as long as the P/S and the COM server are registered in the same hive, everything looks good.

Comment: Couldn't you have it built as is, without modifications, and then register with redirection to HKCU? It looks the safest because you don't really interfere with the magic inside P/S and have it done by switching registry.

Comment: The only way to do that, AFAIK, is to use `ATL::AtlSetPerUserRegistration(true)`, which only affects registration performed by ATL.

Comment: This is ATL capability, and I am talking about a different thing. You LoadLibrary the PS library, then you [`RegOverridePredefKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724901) HKLM somewhere into safe place, then you do `DllRegisterServer` and have the registration redirected. Since you already have certain success with manual registration, this redirection approach looks workable and - more important - can automate the redirection in general.

Comment: Ah, of course. I've only ever used that API for installer-like work. Will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using RegOverridePredefKey is the right answer.
Then register with:

```
regsvr32 /n /i:user C:\src\myCode.dll
```

With "/i:user", regsvr32 calls your the "DllInstall" function instead of DllRegisterServer.

Example implementation of DllInstall:

```
extern "C" STDAPI DllInstall(BOOL bInstall, _In_opt_  LPCWSTR pszCmdLine)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    static const wchar_t szUserSwitch[] = L"user";

    if (pszCmdLine != NULL)
    {
        if (_wcsnicmp(pszCmdLine, szUserSwitch, _countof(szUserSwitch)) == 0)
        {
            ATL::AtlSetPerUserRegistration(true); // is this really needed??
        }
    }

    LSTATUS status = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Classes", 0, 0, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, &hkcu_classes, &disposition);
    if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        status = RegOverridePredefKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, hkcu_classes);
    }
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(status);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (bInstall)
        {
            hr = DllRegisterServer();
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                DllUnregisterServer();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hr = DllUnregisterServer();
        }
    }
}
```